# How to use Class getMethod with lombok @Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am trying to call Class getMethod() method with lombok @Data to call getter of model but i got NoSuchMethod exception. Below are my classes:

**Model class:**

```
@Data
public class Claim {
    private String customerName;
}
```

**usage:**

```
Claim.class.get("getCustomerName", String.class)
```

**Exception:**

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException' exception.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
new PropertyDescriptor("customerName", claim.getClass()).getReadMethod().invoke(claim)
```

for better explaination [click here](https://java2blog.com/invoke-getters-setters-using-reflection-java/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20PropertyDescriptor%20to%20call%20getters%20and%20setters%20using%20reflection.&text=Setter%3A%20Call%20getWriteMethod()%20on,getters%20and%20setters%20on%20that.)